# Lumen - CORS missing allow origin but request suceed

Tags: php, vue.js, lumen

I have a problem with my application Lumen-VueJs

I make a request and the request status is 200 and I receive what I want but on the 'network' the request is blocked. ( screen )
[image: Request blocked in Console]

I have on my app a CorsMiddleware that is like that and that is also added in the bootstrap/app.php

```
<?php

/**
 * Location: /app/Http/Middleware
 */
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CorsMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $headers = [
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => 'POST,GET,PATCH,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS',
            'Access-Control-Max-Age' => '86400',
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => 'Content-Type,API-KEY'
                ];

        if ($request->isMethod('OPTIONS')) {
            return response()->json('', 200, $headers);
        }

        $response = $next($request);

        foreach ($headers as $key => $value) {
            $response->header($key, $value);
        }

        return $response;
    }
}
```

These are the headers of my request :
[image: Request's headers]

I don't understand why I have that error that must be authorized by my Middleware

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: Can you please share the message that is displayed in column `Transfert`?

Comment: Sure, the message is `CORS Missing Allow Origin` , Note that if I use `POSTMAN` it works without any error message

Comment: Thanks. Can you please check if your response contains all the headers you have listed in the code when `POST`ing via Chrome?

Comment: I was on Firefox, when I test on Chrome the message is : ``Cross-Origin Resource Sharing error: MissingAllowOriginHeader`.  And on Firefox I receive the response that I need ( a bearer token ) but on the Chrome console the response is empty

Comment: I was not talking about the response. In the `Headers` tab (`En-têtes` I assume), which headers are listed for `Response` and `Request`? There you can check if your headers are actually sent, i.e. your middleware works as expected.

Comment: I added the screen of my headers in the main message :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238669/discussion-between-johannes-and-fizik26).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing our discussion in the chat, the issue your browser is complaining about is correct. The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is not sent.

This is because your middleware was not called as you have added your middleware to `$app->routeMiddleware` with key `cors`. I assume there is no route that is called `cors`. From [Lumen's GitHub](https://github.com/laravel/lumen/blob/8.x/bootstrap/app.php#L69-L81):

> These can be global middleware that run before and after each request `[$middleware]` into a route or middleware that'll be assigned to some specific routes `[$routeMiddleware]`.

As your CORS middleware should be called for all requests, you need to add it to `$app->middleware`.